# Keyboard working in grub but not in Windows or Fedora 37

Tags: linux, windows-10, keyboard, fedora, grub

I have a Asus FX705DT laptop with dual boot, Fedora 37 and Windows 10, and the following issue:

- the keyboard works in grub, all keys, arrows, letters etc.
- after I boot in either Linux or Windows the keyboard is not working anymore, with 3 exceptions: the FN F11 combination which puts the OS into sleep mode, FN arrow up and down which cycles the intensity of the keyboard backlight, and FN F7/F8 which changes the intensity of the display. This 3 are working in Windows, but not in Fedora.

I check the BIOS settings (UEFI) and saw nothing related to the keyboard.
The BIOS/UEFI was updated to the latest version long before this issue and everything was working fine.
If I attach an USB keyboard, it works. No other key works.

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Did something happen or was done just before the problem arrived? Do you have it when booting from a Linux Live USB or from Windows boot media into the Command Prompt?

Comment: I would say nothing significant. I upgraded my Oracle Virtual Box to the latest version, it's the only thing I recall. No hardware installation, no new devices attached. I also updated Fedora to the latest packages. I did not try to boot from a Linux Live USB, I will try this.

Comment: So I tried a live USB, and it's the same problem.

Comment: That sounds incredible. Sorry, I have no more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the OS (both Linux and Windows 10) did not solve the problem.
I managed to solve by decoupling the BIOS battery from the motherboard for a few seconds.
I still do not know what caused it.